# Update label text every time i collect the point

Tags: python, tkinter

My Problem is that the "Score" is not updating every time I collect the point.
It makes a new label under the game with the new score but not updating my existed one above the game.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect("Benutzer.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Benutzer (username TEXT, password TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (username))")

conn2 = sqlite3.connect("Punkte.db")
c2 = conn2.cursor()

c2.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Punkte (username TEXT, score INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (username))")

conn.commit()
conn2.commit()

points = 0
score_value = 0

def register():
    user = username.get()
    pwd = password.get()

    c.execute("SELECT username FROM Benutzer WHERE username = ?", [user])
    result = c.fetchone()

    if result:
        error_label = tk.Label(login_window, text="Dieser Benutzer existiert bereits.", fg="red")
        error_label.pack()

    else:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Benutzer VALUES ('" + user + "', '" + pwd + "')")
        c2.execute("INSERT INTO Punkte VALUES ('" + user + "', 0)")
        conn.commit()
        conn2.commit()
        create_label = tk.Label(login_window, text="Du hast dich erfolgreich registriert.", fg="green")
        create_label.pack()


def login():
    user = username.get()
    pwd = password.get()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (user, pwd))
    result = c.fetchone()

    if result:
        login_window.destroy()

        score_window = tk.Tk()
        score_window.title("Punktestand")
        score_window.geometry("350x325")

        user_label = tk.Label(score_window, text=f"Willkommen, {user}!")
        user_label.pack()

        score_label = tk.Label(score_window, text="Ihr Punktestand ist:")
        score_label.pack()

        c2.execute("SELECT score FROM Punkte WHERE username = ?", [user])
        score = c2.fetchone()

        if score:
            score_value = tk.Label(score_window, text=score[0])
            score_value.pack()
        else:
            error_message = tk.Label(score_window, text="Kein Punktestand gefunden.")
            error_message.pack()

        canvas = tk.Canvas(score_window, width=300, height=200, bg="white")
        canvas.pack()

        circle = canvas.create_oval(150, 100, 170, 120, fill="blue")
        point = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 10, 10, fill="red")

        def placePoint():
            point
            x = random.randint(0, 290)
            y = random.randint(0, 190)
            canvas.coords(point, x, y, x+10, y+10)

        placePoint()

        def moveLeft(event):
            circle
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle)
            if x1 > 0:
                canvas.move(circle, -10, 0)

        def moveRight(event):
            circle
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle)
            if x2 < 300:
                canvas.move(circle, 10, 0)

        def moveUp(event):
            circle
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle)
            if y1 > 0:
                canvas.move(circle, 0, -10)

        def moveDown(event):
            circle
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle)
            if y2 < 200:
                canvas.move(circle, 0, 10)

        canvas.bind("<Left>", moveLeft)
        canvas.bind("<Right>", moveRight)
        canvas.bind("<Up>", moveUp)
        canvas.bind("<Down>", moveDown)

        canvas.focus_set()

        def checkCollision():
            circle, point
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle)
            x3, y3, x4, y4 = canvas.coords(point)
            cx = (x1 + x2) / 2
            cy = (y1 + y2) / 2
            px = (x3 + x4) / 2
            py = (y3 + y4) / 2
            distance = ((cx - px) ** 2 + (cy - py) ** 2) ** 0.5

            if distance < 10:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        def update():
            circle, point

            if checkCollision():
                placePoint()
                addScore()
            score_window.after(100, update)

        update()

        def addScore():
            user = username.get()

            c2.execute("SELECT score FROM Punkte WHERE username = ?", [user])
            score = c2.fetchone()
            ergebnis = score[0] + 1
            c2.execute("UPDATE Punkte SET score = ? WHERE username = ?", [ergebnis, user])
            conn2.commit()
            score_value = tk.Label(text=ergebnis)
            score_value.pack()

        close_button = tk.Button(score_window, text="Schließen", command=score_window.destroy)
        close_button.pack()

        score_window.mainloop()

    else:
        error_label = tk.Label(login_window, text="Falscher Benutzername oder Passwort.", fg="red")
        error_label.pack()


login_window = tk.Tk()
login_window.title("Anmeldung")
login_window.geometry("325x175")

instruction_label = tk.Label(login_window, text="Bitte geben Sie Ihren Benutzernamen und Ihr Passwort ein.")
instruction_label.pack()

username = tk.StringVar()
password = tk.StringVar()

username_label = tk.Label(login_window, text="Benutzername:")
username_label.pack()
password_label = tk.Label(login_window, text="Passwort:")
password_label.pack()

username_entry = tk.Entry(login_window, textvariable=username)
username_entry.pack()
password_entry = tk.Entry(login_window, textvariable=password, show="*")
password_entry.pack()

login_button = tk.Button(login_window, text="Anmelden", command=login)
login_button.pack()
register_button = tk.Button(login_window, text="Registrieren", command=register)
register_button.pack()

login_window.mainloop()
```

i will, that the line we´re `score_value = tk.Label(score_window, text=score[0]) score_value.pack()` stands, updatet every second or every time i collect a point in the game.

Google and stackoveflow searched about updating label but not helps me

Comment: labels have a set method to update their text. Otherwise, you could use a StringVar

Comment: You already know the cause of the problem, so what stopping you to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you also be passing the score_window as a parameter on subsequent tk.label calls?

Answer (score 0):

Calling tk.Label multiple times creates new labels, without updating the previous ones. You use this yourself in your login window, otherwise the text "Password:" would've been written on top of, and replacing, "Username:"

To be able to update an existing label, create it passing a StringVar as the textvariable argument, instead of using a regular string

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
points_str = tk.StringVar("0")

label = tk.Label(textvariable = points_str)

# update the StringVar, which updates the label who is using it, magically
points_str.set("23")
```